# use different font-size for different font in the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

Say we use helvetica for english and some exotic font(from ascii point of view) for another language in a page.

With the font size being equal, one font looks bigger on the eye.

Is there a way to specify different font size for different font used in a page?

Additionally, since the two languages can be intermingled in a line, we need to align them properly after we resize one of the font. Otherwise the smaller font might have bigger line-spacing at top , smaller line-spacing at bottom.

-- edit

Wow fast responses.
Sadly this is user-posted text like SO's question & answer.
Which is not tagged with different classes.

Comment: If you say language, are the pieces that are in other languages marked as such? For instance, `<section lang="ur">` or something.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trivially set font size different for different languages, as long as you use some markup to distinguish the languages (e.g., `lang` attributes).

However, if the problem is that texts in the same font size look differently sized, then the basic problem is in your choice of fonts. You should normally use one font for copy text, selecting a font that covers all the characters you will need. If you cannot do that for some reason, you should try to select fonts that are compatible, in the sizing sense and otherwise.

Comment: it's a purely aesthetic reason. e.g) helvetica looks best for english (for our eyes) and SomeAsianFont looks best for asian. And how do we get the best of both world was the question if possible.

Comment: what do you mean by `markup` in your sentence? As I pointed out in my edit, its not trivial to assign classes to different languages since it is user-generated content

Comment: Proper esthetics takes into account the use of different characters in text and selects one font, or matching fonts. You cannot avoid this by tuning font sizes. You have now raised the question of recognizing language from user-provided content, which is a different issue (and should be asked separately) and is here a problem only if you make it a problem by insisting on using different fonts for differen languages.

Comment: ok.. fair enough. will try to find different font first. what about the http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang this looks precisely what I wanted. (selecting different languages without assigning different classes manually)

Answer (score 0):

You can change font size using  tags or CSS. I suggest CSS because it is more organized and easier to read.

CSS

```
.firstfont{
font-size: 10px; (or whatever you want)
}

.secondfont{
font-size: 12px; (or whatever you want)
}
```

In the HTML

```
<div class="firstfont">
This is the first font's text
</div>

<div class="secondfont">
This is the second font's text
</div>
```

Alternatively if you don't want to use CSS you can do

```
<div style="font-size:10px">
This is the first font's text
</div>

<div style="font-size:12px">
This is the second font's text
</div>
```

Comment: It's not trivial to assign classes since the text is user-generated.

Comment: if CSS is giving them different fonts as you claim, then it must be distinguishing them somehow; could you not use that same mechanism to set the size?

Comment: Can you please give an example of how the user is inputting information? I think it might make it easier to think of a solution.

Comment: it's like this... Hello Jester .. 안녕

Comment: Spudley, Ok I see what you mean, but Jester's code shows "firstfont" is a class name not the font name like "helvetica". Maybe I'm confused..

Comment: From what I understand it is like Jukka said this is an entirely different problem because you are dealing with language detection on a a micro scale. The best solution is find two fonts that match better.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using CSS, you can use two different classes for each font.

```
.font1
{
font-size:10;
color:#000;(you can use any color over here)
}

.font2{
font-size:11;
color:#efe; (you can use any color over here)
}
```